# How to update props immediately when updating states in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a react app with a parent dashboard component and a child modal component. I have a button in another child component and I'm getting an ID from that button click and firing a function in the Parent dashboard component. I'm setting a state in that function and send the state as props from the Parent dashboard component to the Child modal component to open the modal and show the ID inside the modal body. **The problem is, I need to click twice to open the model and need to click twice to close the modal**. I know that I need to use `state callback` method **but not sure how to**.

Parent Dashboard component:

```
import ProjectModal from './projectModal';
import Card from './card';

class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentId: '',
      open: false
    };
  }

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };

  getPojectId = (projectId) => {
    this.setState({
      open: true,
      currentId: projectId
    })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <ProjectModal
         handleOpen={this.state.open}
         handleClosed={this.handleClose}
         projectID={this.state.currentId}
      />
      <Card getCardId={this.getPojectId} />
    )
  }
}
```

Child modal component:

```
class ProjectModal extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            open: false,
            currentId: ''
        };
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps() {
        this.setState({
            open: this.props.handleOpen,
            currentId: this.props.projectID
        })
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="projectDetailsModal">
                <Dialog
                    open={this.state.open}
                    keepMounted
                    onClose={this.props.handleClosed}
                    aria-labelledby="form-dialog-slide-title"
                    aria-describedby="form-dialog-slide-description"
                >
                    <div className="modalClose" onClick={this.props.handleClosed}>
                        <span>&times;</span>
                    </div>
                    <DialogContent>
                        <div className="centerModal">
                            <div className="projectFormHeader">ID {this.state.currentId}</div>
                        </div>
                    </DialogContent>
                </Dialog>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have open in both components states?

Comment: Any specific reason you're copying the props to the state in the child? Considering you don't seem to do anything with the state other than copy the props to it, it seems unneeded. You can use the props in the child by simply changing `<Dialog
                    open={this.state.open}` to `<Dialog
                    open={this.props.open}`

Comment: @ApplePearPerson I got your point. I can handle all data with props instead copying them to states

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid the use of `componentWillReceiveProps`, its use is discouraged. And in other hand, copy `props` into `state` is an antipattern, in your code there arent any need to do it.

In your Dashboard component try this:

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentId: '',
      open: false
    };
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
```

And, in your Modal, first remove State, you don't need in this component, its pure. Before that, changes all your `this.state` to `this.props`.

Answer (score 0):

what about try to use `newProps` parameter?

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
  if (newProps.handleOpen !== this.props.handleOpen) {
       this.setState({
            open: this.props.handleOpen,
            currentId: this.props.projectID
        })
  }
 }
```

current value is `this.props.handleOpen` , new changed value is `newProps.handleOpen`.

Answer (score 0):

"Ilsanchez" is right. Also you don't need to make 'Child modal' as class component, it could be functional only.